# Joomla component include php library, not working

Tags: php, joomla, include, joomla-component

i'm trying to include a php library into my component front-end, however, when i try to declare a object, it shows error: class not found.

here is some code: (in model)

```
require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/assets/php/phplibrary.php');
     $myclass = new myclass('databaseT');
     $response = $myclass->request('form data');

     return $response;
```

Please help

Comment: Maybe triple check the class name (case sensitive) and the path to the php file + file name?

Comment: thx for comment, i'd check the class etc, it still not working, and also i'd try to place the code in admin controller, site controller,etc it still the same

Comment: Do this: `$str = JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE .'/assets/php/phplibrary.php'; echo $str;`  and see if it actually matches where you are.  You don't mention a Joomla version, but it may not.  Also you might anyway be better off installing it as a library.

Comment: @Elin thx for reply, i have test the path, the path is fine. The Joomla version i am working with is 3.4

Comment: What are the permissions on  the file? Also please add the complete error message to your question.  You may want to turn on joomla debugging

Comment: have you ensured file is getting included or not by $included=require_once(JPATH_COMPONENT_SITE.'/assets/php/phplibrary.php'); var_dump($included);